# chrome://tracing - Tracing paint operations in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

I came across this short video about [Tracing paint operations in Chrome Canary](http://youtu.be/bMZZOzuJCgk?t=1m12s)

I have tried all the options and I can't get to these brilliant features.

**1. Paints (snapshots):**

[image]

**2. Layers view:**

[image]

The video is 1 year old now (it is from April 2013).

Are these features still available?

If yes, how to get to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to show layers and snapshots using the following settings. Note that on the left pane the fully set of options is not visible in the screenshot, however the only item that is checked on the left pane is 'gpu'. All options on the right pane are visible. A smaller number of settings is likely possible:

[image]

Here's a snapshot of what I see. Note that the snapshot includes a full rendering of the webpage:

[image]

My Chrome version is 36.0.1985.125 (Official Build 283153)

Comment: Based on your screenshot you are not seeing the snapshot of the site you are visiting, which is the main request of the question.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about this, I did actually find some settings that also renders the snapshot and updated the answer.